# Android/Java: How to get Targets & Macros in Android like in iOS?

Tags: java, android, ios, preprocessor, manifold

I would like to create targets & macros like in iOS on the Android side.
I read the [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#groovy) but impossible to understand

1/ how to get targets/schemes like in iOS:
[image: Targets]

2/ how to get preprocessor macros like in iOS:
[image: Preprocessors macros]
[image: Code macros]

I also checked that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352894/how-to-subproject-or-target-multiple-app-equivalents-in-ios-10-xcode-8-swift) and that [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352894/how-to-subproject-or-target-multiple-app-equivalents-in-ios-10-xcode-8-swift) but it never mentions how to create the macros part and how to compile the differents APK variants like the targets in iOS...

**EDIT 1:**
For the variant and the flavor, I found exactly the video I needed:  [Video variant & flavor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-PTrjFaDJk)

For the icon for each variant : [Video icon change by variants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Umzk3tAwiI)

For the preprocessoring, I tried to install [Manifold](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold/blob/master/manifold-deps-parent/manifold-preprocessor/readme.md) but impossible to understand how to install it...

**EDIT 2:**
I found [that way](http://harlie.com/using-gradle-for-processing-android-flavor-and-buildtype-with-ifdef-in-java-code/) to use the preprocessor, but it seems not to work...

Comment: This kind of macro is not specific to iOS, it is a specificity of c-like language. Before compilation there is first pass on called pre processor to process the macros = replace code or select (#if) code to be used. Look for : “Java preprocessing “ you may find some workaround. You may also use a c pre processor with Java code but that mean you have to preprocess the code to other have code which will be the source code for Java.

Comment: preprocessors (the things that evaluate macros) and macros aren't really a thing in Java or Kotlin.  There's other ways to achieve similar results, but they do it differently.  What those ways are really depends on what you're trying to do.  For example in the screenshot above, you'd define the FST_BRAND to a value in your BuidConfig variable and do a standard if statement.  You can find some old Java preprocessors out there, but the idea is largely abandoned-  it just doesn't work for the language and tools.

Comment: @PtitXav for the Java preprocessing, I found the Manifold solution, but impossible to understand how to install it...